# Getting a return of 0 for SQL Server COUNT() and GROUP BY SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm using `COUNT()` and `GROUP BY` to populate a chart showing sales for last week by day. However it will only return days that have sales and not days with no sales.

For example:

```
SELECT  
    DATEPART(DAY,DateSubmitted) AS DayOf,
    COUNT(*) AS DayCount 
FROM 
    [User] 
WHERE 
    DATEPART(WEEK, getdate() -7) = DATEPART(WEEK, DateSubmitted) 
    AND YEAR(GETDATE()) = YEAR(DateSubmitted)  
GROUP BY 
    DATEPART(DAY, DateSubmitted)  

UNION ALL

SELECT 
    DATEPART(DAY, DateSubmitted) AS DayOf,
    COUNT(*) AS DayCount 
FROM 
    [User] 
WHERE 
    DATEPART(WEEK, getdate() -7) = DATEPART(WEEK, DateSubmitted) 
    AND YEAR(GETDATE()) = YEAR(DateSubmitted) 
    AND 'CODE HERE TO GET DAYS WHERE COUNT GETS NO RESULTS AND ASSIGN 0'
GROUP BY 
    DATEPART(DAY, DateSubmitted)
```

I've been trying a `UNION` where I would ask for any days with no rows being returned (due to no sales that day) to fill the full 7 days in a week.  I have been unable to figure out the SQL to append row results with a count of zero/null in addition to counts with more than 0. You can see the results below do not include the zero sales on the 13th and 19th of last week.

What I see now:

[image]

What I want to see:

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If there are no rows it can't return a row. What you need to do is use another table as the base table for your query with a left join to your count query. Then you will have rows in the result when there is no other data.

Comment: Makes sense @SeanLange .  I have tried that will little luck but understanding the reasoning in your reply.

Comment: This is one of the great uses for a numbers or tally table. Your query is also nonSARGable the way you are checking your dates.

Comment: Thanks @SeanLange I'm looking into fixing the nonSARGEable issue as well.

Comment: Take a look at my answer of the one from shawnt00. Both of them deal with the sargability issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're dealing with a limited number of days you probably don't need to use some of the more complicated ways of generating a table of dates. The real trick then is to use an outer join against the list of dates and then count the results that find a match which will give you the zeroes that you want.

```
with dates as (
    select
        cast(dateadd(day, n,
            dateadd(day, -datepart(weekday, current_timestamp) - 6, current_timestamp)
        ) as date) as DayOf
    from (values (0), (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6)) m(n)
)
select dates.DayOf, count(u.DateSubmitted) as DayCount
from dates left outer join [User] u on cast(u.DateSubmitted as date) = dates.DayOf
group by dates.DayOf
```

You could add a date range filter to the join condition if the table is large and the column is indexed:

```
from dates left outer join [User] u on u.DateSubmitted = dates.DayOf
    and u.DateSubmitted >= 
        cast(dateadd(day, -datepart(weekday, current_timestamp) - 6, current_timestamp) as date) 
    and u.DateSubmitted  <
        cast(dateadd(day, -datepart(weekday, current_timestamp) + 1, current_timestamp) as date)
```

You'll want to be careful using `datepart(week, ...`) near the start of a new year. I'm not sure it you only want to see a partial week starting on January 1 or if you want to include days from the previous year.

Comment: Getting closer with this solution as well.  I now get all 7 days from last week but the COUNT is zero for all days.  Still fiddling...

Comment: Probably a date with time issue. Try: `cast(u.DateSubmitted as date) = dates.DayOf`. I also edited to cast `DayOf` to a date in the CTE.

Comment: Oh man that last edit did it @shawnt00 !  Now I just need to learn how to translate the similar concept in my head of a table to reference to working code using your example.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of using a tally table for this kind of thing. I actually have this entire cte set as a view on my system so I don't have to worry about writing it over and over. I also changed up the where predicates so that you can leverage indexing on the DateSubmitted column.

```
WITH
    E1(N) AS (select 1 from (values (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1))dt(n)),
    E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b), --10E+2 or 100 rows
    E4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b), --10E+4 or 10,000 rows max
    cteTally(N) AS 
    (
        SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E4
    )

SELECT t.N AS DayOf
    , COUNT(u.DateSubmitted) AS DayCount 
FROM cteTally t
left join [User] u on t.N = DATEPART(DAY, DateSubmitted)
WHERE DateSubmitted >= dateadd(week, datediff(week, 0, getdate()) - 1, 0) --Beginning of last week
    AND DateSubmitted < dateadd(week, datediff(week, 0, getdate()), 0) --Beginning of this week
GROUP BY t.N
```

--EDIT--

Here I will show you how I would do this on my system. First I would create my cteTally as a view. This is something I use all the time and it generates 10,000 rows nearly instantly with zero reads.

```
create View [dbo].[cteTally] as

WITH
    E1(N) AS (select 1 from (values (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1))dt(n)),
    E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b), --10E+2 or 100 rows
    E4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b), --10E+4 or 10,000 rows max
    cteTally(N) AS 
    (
        SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E4
    )
select N from cteTally
GO
```

Now for your actual problem I would create the User table. In this case I just created a temp table to make it easier to work with.

```
create table #User
(
    DateSubmitted datetime
)

insert #User
select '2016-03-14' union all
select '2016-03-14' union all
select '2016-03-15' union all
select '2016-03-16' union all
select '2016-03-17' union all
select '2016-03-18';
```

Like your sample this has no data for the first or last day of the week. I needed to adjust my query a bit to accommodate what you are trying to accomplish. My first post incorrectly had the date check in the where clause which effectively turned the join into an inner join. I moved those to the join predicates. This then requires us to limit the tally table to only the 7 days we want. There are other ways this could be accomplished by using DAYOFWEEK(u.DateSubmitted) but I want to maintain sargability. To accomplish I needed to add some conditions to the where clause.

This could probably be tweaked a bit but it will in fact produce the expected results for the prior week. One caveat is that if your prior week spans the end of the year this will need a little tweaking to accommodate that but shouldn't be a big deal.

```
SELECT t.N AS DayOf
    , COUNT(u.DateSubmitted) AS DayCount 
FROM cteTally t
left join #User u on t.N = DATEPART(DAY, DateSubmitted)
AND DateSubmitted >= dateadd(week, datediff(week, 0, getdate()) - 1, 0) --Beginning of last week
    AND DateSubmitted < dateadd(week, datediff(week, 0, getdate()), 0) --Beginning of this week
where t.N >= DAY(dateadd(week, datediff(week, 0, getdate()) - 1, 0)) - 1
    and t.N < day(dateadd(week, datediff(week, 0, getdate()), 0)) - 1
GROUP BY t.N
```

Comment: I think you need to use `count(u.DateSubmitted)` so that you return a zero.

Comment: Ahh yes. Thanks @shawnt00

Comment: This is getting closer however the date range needed is from Sunday to Saturday of each week. That said I am still not getting a "Date 13th Value 0"  Or a "Date 19th Value=0" the two days from last calendar week with no sales (DateSubmitted datetime field).  I can probably work it out from this proper code though.  Trying now...

Comment: Day 0 is a Monday so that throws off the calculated date range a little bit.

Comment: I'll be using this example and @shawnt00 as well to improve my SQL skills.  Thanks so much for the combined help!

Answer (score 1):

Here's another option for using a `CTE` to generate a list of numbers from 1 to 31.  I left off your `where` clause and made up some column names for the example, but you can of course modify the aggregation part of the query as needed.

```
;with dates as (select 1 as number
                union all
                select number + 1
                from dates
                where number < 31)


select a.number as DayOf, count(eventID) as DayCount from Dates a
left join MyTable b
on a.number = datepart(day, b.datesubmitted)
group by a.number
order by a.number
```

SQL Fiddle Example http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/93a0c/3.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DATEPART(DAY, DateSubmitted) AS DayOf,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEPART(WEEK, getdate() -7) = DATEPART(WEEK, DateSubmitted) 
                  then 1 ELSE 0 END
            ) AS DayCount 
  FROM [User] 
 WHERE YEAR(GETDATE()) = YEAR(DateSubmitted)  
 GROUP BY DATEPART(DAY, DateSubmitted)
```

you may need to use SUM rather than COUNT